# Safe convert function

Tags: c#

Can someone explain me this code, especially I'm not sure how generic function as parameter works:

```
result.Notes= orderInfo.Notes.SafeConvert(x => (Communication.OrderNotes)x);            

public static TOut[] SafeConvert<TIn, TOut>(
        this TIn[] input,
        Func<TIn, TOut> converter)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return input
            .Where(i => i != null)
            .Select(converter)
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how generic function as parameter works" Are you talking about `Select(converter)`?

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate what part exactly you need help with. This method also appears to be a hopelessly convoluted alternative to the method `Cast<T>()`. But it's Friday, my in-head compiler may be off.

Answer (score 1):

SafeConvert is a generic [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx). The first parameter (an array of the generic type TIn) is implicitly added when the method is invoked on an array of some type (in this case maybe a note?). The method also requires an function as a parameter. This function must take an instance of the type TIn and return a TOut instance. So, you'd invoke this method on an array of some type, supply a lambda expression or a delegate function, and it will return an array of whatever type your supplied function returns. It does this by using Linq to filter out nulls, run each item in the array through the method, then return the enumeration of those items as an array.

In the implementation you've given, it takes the "Notes" of "orderInfo" and explicitly casts them to "CommunicationOrderNotes."

Here's another way you could invoke the method.

var decimals = new [] {5, 3, 2, 1}.SafeConvert(someInt => (decimal) someInt);

Comment: Thank you Timothy.Why generic method "SafeConvert<TIn, TOut>"
has 2 type parameters - can it have only SafeConvert<TOut>? What defines the number of types in <> brackets ? 
And second, Func<TIn, TOut> converter doesn't have any input parameters, otherwise it should be "Func<TIn, TOut> converter(TIn, par1, par2,..)"? If without input parameter, how can operate on TIn - can you explain a little bit?

Comment: SafeConvert need 2 generics based upon its logic, one to represent what you're coming from and the other you're going to. A function may have as many generics as it needs based upon the number of unique types involved (some functions can have double-digits of types). The developer designing the method or generic class determines the number of generics. Also, the Func<TIn, TOut> is just a method definition, it does have a single input parameter, as a Func takes inputs and returns the output (all the generics except for the last are considered input types while the last is the output).

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known as an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx). It's a static function that allows you to "add" methods to types without modifying the original code. It's somewhat analogous to the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) but there's [controversy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888116/the-decorator-pattern-extension-methods-in-c-sharp) about whether it's actually an implementation of that particular pattern.

"Under the hood," at least, extension methods are just "syntactic sugar" for calling a static method, but you can call them as if they were an instance method of the extended object (in this case, arrays).

The `<TIn, TOut>` part means that `TIn` and `TOut` are some type you haven't specified yet (but that you intend to specify what they *actually* are when you go to use the class). To understand the purpose of this, think of a Linked List - really, the implementation of a Linked List of integers isn't any different than the code for a Linked List of strings, so you'd like it to be the case that you can create a single class and specify later that you want a list of integers or a list of strings or whatever. You definitely would *not* want to have to create an implementation for every single possible type of object - that would require a massive amount of redundant code.

Now, for the LINQ query:

```
return input
        .Where(i => i != null)
        .Select(converter)
        .ToArray();
```

LINQ (Language Integrated Query) is a mechanism for querying different types of collections using a single syntax. You can use it to query .NET collections (like they're doing here), [XML documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx), or [databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx), for example.

LINQ Queries take an [anonymous function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx) of some kind and apply the operator to the collection in some way (see below).

Going through this query;

```
.Where(i => i != null)
```

As the name suggests, `Where` applies a filter. When applied to a collection, it returns a second collection with all of the elements of the first collection that match the filter condition. The

```
i => i != null
```

bit is the anonymous function that acts as a filter. Basically, what this is saying is "give me a collection with all of the members of the array that aren't null."

The `Select` method applies a transform to every element of the collection and returns the result as a second collection. In this case, you apply whatever transformation you passed in as an argument to the method.

It might sound slightly odd to think of code as data, but this is actually very routine in some other languages like F#, Lisp, and Scala. ("Under the hood", C# is implementing this behavior in an object-oriented way, but the effect is the same).

The basic idea of this function, then, is that it converts an array of one type to an array of a second type, filtering out all of the null references.